# LINQ to Entity Framework queries in a generic controller

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to write a generic controller for a Web Api and I'm running into this one problem, LINQ to EF doesn't like what I do.

Here's what I've tried.

Here's the default controller:

```
public class DefaultController<TEntity> : ApiController where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    private AppEntities Context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> AppDbSet;

    public DefaultController()
    {
        Context = new AppEntities();
        AppDbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get(int Id)
    {
        var entity = AppDbSet.Where(x => x.IdValue == Id);

        if (entity == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(entity);   
    }
}
```

So I've decided to create an interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int IdValue { get; }
}
```

And the database first approach generates a .cs file for each table, and I add some meat to it in a separate file:

```
public partial class User : IEntity
{
    public int IdValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work compilation wise, but fails at runtime.

```
The specified type member 'IdValue' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

So I'm trying to figure out how I could refer to my context entities's properties in a LINQ queries in the generic controller, but this fails.

Any ideas ?

PS: I'm aware generic controller can become problematic, but I'd like to learn how to make one in the event where it can become handy for simple models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want base interface with Id, you should have all entities with this property mapped to column in db. There should not be proxy properties like

```
    public int IdValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Id;
        }
    }
```

So you should create interface

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id{ get; }
}
```

And all your inherited entities should have this property

```
public partial class User : IEntity
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
}
```